# How to do a group by in the Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, group-by, custom-fields

I have a drivers post type which has a relationship called team. I want to group drivers by team so I can output them together in their groupings 'teams'. Hopefully that makes sense. I don't really understand the documentation I have a tried a few things but it seems to be missing details. This is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php 
  $type = 'drivers';
  $args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 0,
  );
  
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

  get_template_part( 'team-driver' );
endwhile;
?>
```

Here is my post type.
[image: Note the team relationship]

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
<?php
// get all the categories
$cats = get_categories(); 
// loop through the categries
foreach ($cats as $cat)
{
    // Get the cateogory ID
    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
    //Header for the cateogry
    echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
    // Make a custom wordpress query
    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=12");
    // start wordpress loop
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php 
    echo '<hr/>'; 
    endwhile;
    endif; // End of WordPress loop
} // End of foreach loop through category
?>
```

If you want to get only one category (drivers) then

```
<?php
$cat_name = 'drivers';
$term = get_term_by('name', $cat_name, 'category');
$cat_id=$term->term_id;
query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=12");
// start wordpress loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php 
   echo '<hr/>'; 
   endwhile;
   endif;   
?>
```

May be this one can help you

```
<?php
$cat_names = array('team1', 'team2', 'team3');
foreach($cat_names as $cat)
{
    $term = get_term_by('name', $cat, 'category');
    $cat_id=$term->term_id;
    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=12");
    // start wordpress loop
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php 
    echo '<hr/>'; 
    endwhile;
    endif;  
}   
?>
```

Comment: Hi, it's not categories I need. I need to group by my teams so I can output: Team 1: Driver 1 from team 1, driver 2 from team 1 then Team 2: Driver 1 from team 2, driver 2 from team 2.

Comment: Thanks, for the help but I am confused. I am not using categories I am using post types. I have the post type drivers and I want the team field which is a relationship field to group them so I have the drivers group by team because at the moment I can display them as a team they are just randomly output. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am not using categories for this so it's not working. You can see the custom fields of my driver post type in the image I have added. It would be easier if I created a relation in my team post type to to each driver a one to manny. Is basically a join and then a group by, at the moment I have a many to one.